# How can I perform mathematical operations on array elements referencing i+1 or i-1 indexes?

Tags: r, dplyr

I could write the following code in almost any language. `subtractPrevious` takes an array and subtracts the `i+1`st value from the `i`th value. How do I do this kind of calculation using R? It seems like a job for `lapply` or maybe a `dplyr` function.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
subtractPrevious <- function(x){
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
       if (i == 1) {
           y[1] <- NA
       } else {
           y[i] <- x[i] - x[i-1]
       }
    }
    return(y)
}

y <- subtractPrevious(x)
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially the `diff` function, padded with NA at the beginning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a built-in function `diff` for this:

```
c(NA,diff(x))
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this:

```
   y <- x - c(0,x[1:length(x)-1])
```

By way of explanation (as requested in the comments), I am concatenating 0 to the front of a new vector formed by shifting the original right by one (and chopping off the last element which falls off the edge).

The nice thing is that it uses only core R and generalizes to other cases (as requested in the question title). So for example if I want to subtract the subsequent values I can do something like:

```
   y <- x - c(x[2:length(x)],0)
```

I use these things all the time for referencing lagged variables, differenceing, etc....

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: Sure. But it is the most basic usage of a vector and the c operator, both fundamental to the core of R. See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html

Comment: `diff` is probably still better for this - it has a `lag=` argument which you can specify how far you want to go back. E.g. `c(rep(NA,n),diff(x,lag=n))` as a general pattern will work.

Comment: Yes, but diff only goes as far as diff goes. This uses vector subsetting which is useful for worlds of things and is fundamental to R. It is not for nothing that Hadley Wickham spends a whole chapter on subsetting but barely mentions diff. But it is a matter of taste I suppose.

Comment: Weird all the flack I am getting for this answer. It is a pretty straightforward answer and a very common technique. I will admit diff is less error prone though. That is an advantage.

Comment: @MikeWise - I'm not intending to give flack. Simply pointing out alternatives. In this case, you could also use `c(rep(0,n),head(x,-n))`, and a similar version using `tail` - there's many ways to skin a cat, including your quite flexible answer.

Comment: I am a little torn. Ben Bolker's answer directly addresses the question, but MikeWise's answer is closer to what I was seeking. I'd prefer a general approach where I might use an arbitrary function. Maybe I want to multiply the x[i+1] by x[i], etc. I think Mike's answer gets closer, but I will probably aware the green check to Ben for being exact...